# If there is no else-if, how come we can do multiple else-if and not multiple else?

Tags: c++, if-statement

In the following video (19:46) Cherno says "else if(x<y){}" is equal to "else {if(x<y){}}", or that and else if statment is not a keyword but just a combination of one-line else statment and an if statment.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEgCT87KOfc

Now if that is true, i should not be able to write more than one else if statments since else cannot be repeated.

is it that if an else is followed by an if it is repeatable.

could someone shed some light

Comment: `else` can be repeated if you also repeat `if`. If you have 10 ifs you can have 10 elses.

Comment: The case where the distinction is important is `if ... if ... else ...`.  Without the braces, the dangling `else` must be paired with the closest `if`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `if` of the `else if` can also have an `else`.

Then that `else` can also have an `if`, and that `if` can have an `else`, and the chain can continue indefinitely.

The structure can also be visualized this way:

```
if (test0)
    true0statement;
else
    if (test1)
        true1statement;
    else
        if (test2)
            true2statement;
        else
            false2statement;
```

Then we can merely combine lines and change the indentation to have:

```
if (test0)
    true0statement;
else if (test1)
    true1statement;
else if (test2)
    true2statement;
else
    false2statement;
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ standard doesn't even mention a construct called `else if`, because it's just a combination of two `if` statements (as was explained in your video).

(Simplified) syntax of `if` statement is:

```
if ([condition]) [statementIfTrue] else [statementIfFalse]
```

Where each `[statement]` could be a single statement or a block (in `{}`). Since `if` is a statement, you can use it as statement in `else` branch, which results in our good old `else if`.

You can break it down into lines to make it more clear:

```
if ([condition]) 
    [statementIfTrue] 
else 
    [statementIfFalse]
```

When we substitute `[statementIfFalse]` with another `if` statement:

```
if ([condition1]) 
    [statementIfTrue] 
else 
    if ([condition]) [statementIfTrue] else [statementIfFalse]
```

---

In practice this is not an important distinction, more of a tidbit.